# Null Values in XML, converting excel from python

Tags: python, excel, xml, xsd, openpyxl

currently trying to convert an excel spreedsheet into a xml file in python. Im using the following skeleton code,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from yattag import Doc, indent

wb = load_workbook("excel_file.xlsx")
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# Create Yattag doc, tag and text objects

doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
xml_header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
xml_schema = '<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"></xs:schema>'

doc.asis(xml_header)
doc.asis(xml_schema)

with tag('Row'):
    # Use ws.max_row for all rows
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=100, min_col=1, max_col=5):
        row = [cell.value for cell in row]
        with tag("Row"):
            with tag("Column1"):
                text(row[2])
            with tag("column2"):
                text(row[1])
            with tag("string _ column"):
                text(row[0])
            with tag("Date_column"):
                text(row[3].strftime("%m/%d/Y"))
            with tag("integer column"):
                text(row[4])
result = indent(
    doc.getvalue(),
    indentation = '    ',
    indent_text = False
)
with open("xml_output_file_name.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

In the past I did have problems with date columns in excel outputting to xml, but was able to fix with a quick strftime("%m/%d/Y") to date columns.

My excel sheet has about 35 columns, and the data itself is such that if one column has a cell, then there should be no element in other columns. Thus some columns have missing values, and that is alright.

Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is so that the xml output can pick up on these missing elements in columnsf. I would like the output to be like.

```
<Column1></Column1>
```

For row 1 when column 1 is missing. In my excel file I have multiple columns so I want to apply it to those as well.

Is that possible? I also did look into xsi:nil, but not sure if it will give me the desired output and the form I want. But will use it as a last resort.

Currently, I have been able to get the code to run, but only if I go into the excel file and replace all empty cells with "NA". Previously with empty cells, I would get errors when running the script with errors of "Non-Object". It does run with NA but it will be read as a string for that column and thats not what I want.

How can I achieve

```
<column1></column1>
```

for empty cells in rows?

Comment: Sounds like you need some logic to check the values of the various cells. At the moment you are always creating child elements.

Comment: I have been looking into to have xml declare, xsi:nil when a column element is empty. Would something like that work? I would prefer to have every column print out for each row.